# Add event listener to template string in a render function

Tags: javascript, html

so wrote a simple script:

```
function Component(renderTarget){  
  this.target = document.querySelector(renderTarget);

  this.number = 0;
  this.increment = 1;

  this.goUp = function(){
    this.number = this.number + this.increment;
    this.render();
  }

  this.goDown = function(){
    this.number = this.number - this.increment;
    this.render();
  }

  this.render = function(){    
   this.target.innerHTML = '';
   this.target.innerHTML += `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="number">${this.number}</div>
      <div class="selector">
        <div class="up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="down"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>`;
  }

  this.init = function(that){
    that.render();
  }(this);
}

var myComponent = new Component('.target');
```

which basically renders some HTML to a div with the class "target". Now, I want to add an event listener to `.up` and `.down` and bind them to the component functions. Which is the correct way of doing this?

You can [fork this codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrellrummage/pen/dvzzom).

Thanks in advance!
PS: I know I can use `class` and arrow functions, etc. but this is just for testing.

EDIT: [Working version](http://codepen.io/tyrellrummage/pen/WpEZjO). This works but I don't know if it's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I can query the divs after I render them and store them in variables, and then bind them to function but maybe it's not the right way to do it, I just want to know what's the best way to do it, the good practice (:

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I edited the post with a working solution, but I want to know if it's correct to do it this way. I'd think the correct is binding the event directly from the template string or something like that, but I don't even know if it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone and their aunt has their own best practice

This would be my approach: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWyrNV)

```
this.target.querySelector('.up').addEventListener('click', this.goUp)
this.target.querySelector('.down').addEventListener('click', this.goDown)
```

You need to add eventlisteners after the render has taken place. Unless you want to attach events to the target and delegate events with custom logic.

I prefer binds to self/that for eventlisteners

In addition your working version fails with multiple components. Know that you can do .querySelector on an element

Comment: Thanks, I only have one question, suppose I have +1000 of this components, wouldn't be slow to have two event listeners for each component?

Comment: Not really. In practice javascript is fast enough to not be noticeable. If you want to have one even listener for all components you will cause a different problem: You have to listen to all click events then determine what was clicked. The slowest thing in javascript is modifying the DOM. So i suggest you simplify your rendering method of your component.
I made some minor optimisations in my example: I moved the Component functions to the prototype so all instances share the same functions, and i updated incrementing functions to update only the `div.number`'s value